# R: How can I use named arguments to match & edit the names of a list of named objects

Tags: r, list, methods, names

I am trying  to figure out how to create a function to take a set of named arguments, with argument values taken from a particular list, and modify the list by replacing elements named (in the element names of the list but the element values of the function arguments) with the argument names of the function arguments. (This vector of  names is first taken from a dataframe, though I do not think that matters and haven't included it below). Arguments that evaluate to more than one name, or that represent ranges via a numerical or logical vectors, are saved separately in quoted form for later processing.

That seems like a straightforward  enough problem, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it. The critical thing is that it has to be done entirely programmatically.  My real function will have an uncertain and potentially large number of arguments as described below.

To illustrate what I am talking about, here is an example "framework" function, missing the guts that would actually make the changes:

```
ChangeIt <- function(dog = NULL, cat = NULL, cow = NULL, ...){
xx <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h") 
#  missing stuff here
if (is.NULL(cow)) print("No cows!")
list(xx, complex_assignments = list())
}
```

Here is a set of possible values for named arguments for the function above.

```
ChangeIt(dog = "b", cat = "a", yak = "f", eel = "g", zoo = 3:5)
```

And this is what ChangeIt should return, based on those values. (This is a description, not how it would literally print)

`"No cows!"` (Printed as side-effect).

Then return:

```
list(xx = c("cat", "dog", "c", "d", "e", "yak", "eel", "h"), 
complex_assignments = list("zoo = 3:5"))
```

You see that the values of the named arguments are used to match the elements in the original list, while the name from that argument is converted to text and then replaces the identified element. That's the goal.

Just to explainain my purpose, want to maintain two separate sets of names for a dataframe, one for the face it shows the world, and a second set accessible only to the methods I am writing for this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
ChangeIt <- function(dog = NULL, cat = NULL, cow = NULL, ...){
  cc <- match.call()
  cc[[1]] <- quote(list)
  allargs <- eval(cc)
  xx <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
  toreplace <- sapply(allargs, function(x) {length(x)==1 && x %in% xx})
  xx <- replace(xx, match(unlist(allargs[toreplace]), xx), names(allargs[toreplace]))
  if (is.null(cow)) print("No cows!")
  list(xx=xx, complex_assignments = allargs[!toreplace])
}

ChangeIt(dog = "b", cat = "a", yak = "f", eel = "g", zoo = 3:5)
```

Here we use `match.call()` to grab all the function call and pass it off to `list()` to generate a list of all the values. Then we can can use that like a regular list to the transformations you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! That does it for me.  I am actually quite excited by this -- it enables my simple-minded approach to S3 class construction. Now all I need it to figure out whether it makes more sense to store the vector constructed as above as an attribute of the DF or in a new column (or some other way).